# E_NOINTERFACE after upgrade of VB6

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, vb6-migration

After upgrading a VB 6 based application exposing a COM interface, 
COM Clients (in .NET) built against the previous version receive `E_NOINTERFACE` errors.

The error message (translated),

> Cannot convert COM-object of type `AProduct.AClass` to interface of type `AProduct._AClass` ...

What went wrong here?

What is the cause of the `E_NOINTERFACE` error?

I *thought* that once an interface was published to COM it cannot be changed; a new interface (with unique UUID) should be published which can inherit the old one, thus i reasoned that the interface might have been updated (extended) incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Version Compatibility setting in your VB 6.0 project? (See the Component tab of your project properties)

If it's not Binary Compatibility then the GUIDs for the interfaces and events exposed by your component may have been changed when you compiled the DLL.

Check out these resources for more information

[How To Use Project and Binary Compatibility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161137)

[Setting up a COM component project in Visual Basic 6.0](http://authors.aspalliance.com/stevesmith/articles/vbcomsetup.asp)

Comment: Thanks for Pointing these out, 
it seems that this has actually happened (the VB6 App is from an external vendor).

Is there any possibility of patching a Runtime Callable Wrapper in order to work around changed GUIDs?